# How to handle multiple key board inputs despite of the number of inputs in python without an error?

Tags: python

I want to get 3 keyboard inputs in python program of 3 countries from the user. But at least 1 or 2 countries are enough. How to handle the value error I'm getting.

```
country1, country2, country3 = input("Write up to three comma-separated countries for which you want to extract data: ").split(",")
```

When typed only one input,

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)

Answer (score 0):

you can take the input as a list of countries

```
x = [x for x in input("provide comma sep countries").split(',')]
```